# How to encode a repeated google.protobuf.any?

Tags: protocol-buffers, nanopb

I have a message and I would like to package it into an any repeated google proto type::
Is there a way to encode an repeated any message type?

Can I even use repeated tag with google.protobuf.any?

```
message Onesensor{
    string name=1
    string type=2
    int32_t reading=3
}


/** Any Message **/
message RepeatedAny{
repeated google.protobuf.any sensors = 1;
}
```

I am looking for an example, currently using nanopb to encode.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is just a regular message.

https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/tree/master/tests/any_type shows how to encode a single Any message, encoding many is like encoding any array. You'll have a choice between allocating statically, allocating dynamically or using callbacks. Or you can just encode a single subfield at a time into output stream, because concatenating encoded concatenates arrays in protobuf format.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my issue, I cannot use(repeated tag on the google.protobuf.any, as I would like to append the **RepeatedAny** messages in the final binary):

```
message Onesensor{
    string name=1
    string type=2
    int32_t reading=3
}

message RepeatedAny{
repeated google.protobuf.any sensors = 1;
}
```

Instead I should use something like this:

```
message Onesensor{
    string name=1
    string type=2
    int32_t reading=3
}

message SensorAny{
google.protobuf.any sensor = 1;
}

message RepeatedAny{
repeated SensorAny sensors = 1;
}
```

I should not use the repeated tag on the google.protobuf.any, I should be using it on a message that contains the google.protobuf.any instead, so that the protobinary can contain the format (sensors1), (sensors2).....(sensorsN), one or more **SensorAny** messages.

Below is the sample code, if someone finds this question in the future for **nanopb**:

```
    /* First encode the SensorAny message by setting the value of the first field,
       The first field of this message is of type google.protobuf.any, so it should have
       1. sensor.type_url
       2. sensor.value
    */

    void* pBufAny = calloc(1, sBufSize);
    pb_ostream_t ostream_any = pb_ostream_from_buffer(pBufAny, sBufSize);
    SensorAny SensorAnyProto = SensorAny_init_default;
    SensorAnyProto.has_message = true;
    SensorAnyProto.sensor.type_url.arg = "type.googleapis.com/SensorAny.proto";
    SensorAnyProto.sensor.type_url.funcs.encode = Proto_encode_string;
    ProtoEncodeBufferInfo_t BufInfo = {
            .Buffer = pBuf, /* I have already filled and encoded Onesensor message previously as pBuf */
            .BufferSize = ostream.bytes_written,
    };
    SensorAnyProto.sensor.value.funcs.encode = Proto_encode_buffer;
    SensorAnyProto.sensor.value.arg = &BufInfo;
    pb_encode(&ostream_any, SensorAny_fields, &SensorAnyProto);
    free(pBuf);


    // Now Use the above encoded Any message buffer pBufAny to set the first repeated field in RepeatedAny

    RepeatedAny SensorAnyRepeated = RepeatedAny_init_default;
    ProtoEncodeBufferInfo_t AnyBufInfo = {
            .Buffer = pBufAny,
            .BufferSize = ostream_any.bytes_written,
    };

    AnyRepeated.sensors.arg=&AnyBufInfo;
    AnyRepeated.sensors.funcs.encode = Proto_encode_buffer;

    void* pBufAnyRepeated = calloc(1, sBufSize);
    pb_ostream_t ostream_repeated = pb_ostream_from_buffer(pBufAnyRepeated, sBufSize);
    !pb_encode(&ostream_repeated, RepeatedAny_fields, &AnyRepeated);
    free(pBufAny);
```